# How to subtract date by days and keep the format

Tags: sas

This may be a simple question but I want to subtract 6 days from 01/09/2012 and keep the 
format of DD/MM/YYYY how would I do this. Also if I compare this with another date in the same format does SAS actually compare the dates so if I said

```
If (Date1<Date2) /*Does this work in SAS */
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SAS dates are simply stored as the number of days since 01JAN1960 - so just subtract six :-)
See my log:

```
44   data _null_;
45   date1 = '01SEP2012'd;
46   date2 = date1 - 6;
47   put date2= ddmmyys10.; /* the format you need */
48   if (date1 < date2) then put 'false'; /* this DOES work in SAS */
49   else put date1= date2=; /* unformatted - num of days*/
50   run;

date2=26/08/2012
date1=19237 date2=19231
```

Comment: I like the way SAS treats dates